# How can I slow down my story without drama?

Tags: dramatic-writing, action

Been reading through my stories, and I've noticed that there's a lot of shooty-shooty-bang-bang where people fight each other, but not a whole lot of drama which I feel like I probably should add so that the story slows down a bit. I think one of the two reasons I didn't put any is because I'm pretty bad at it, and the second reason is I just don't like it. I'd rather watch people punching each other than people confessing their undying love for each other and then breaking up next episode/chapter. I'm already doing a lot of the internal musings of the MC to try and slow stuff down, but it's not quite enough.

Are there any other things I can use to slow down the story besides drama?

Comment: "confessing their undying love for each other and then breaking up next episode/chapter" is **bad** drama.  What is the point of the story?  People aren't just shooting at each other for giggles.  Why is all the shooting going on?  Why are you telling me about it?  Why should I care if your characters are killing/being killed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would you do if you were in your character’s position? How would you act? What would you see? Touch? Smell? Why would you act the way you did? Because you were scared? Why? What would you be thinking? How would you process this? After the action, does your character feel guilty? Yes? Write it down! Do they still feel scared? Write it down!

Basically ask yourself a bunch of questions about your characters thoughts and feelings, and then write it down. Make sure they act according to how they felt.

Answer (score 0):

You could add in more descriptive language or foreshadowing to your story to slow down the plot a little. You could also add additional dialogue/internal dialogue that would show the characters' emotions without being too dramatic, but still slowing the plot down. You could also add extra supporting characters that would help to move the story along, or could create a problem or roadblock for the main characters/protagonists.